# Querying extensions on X509 certificates using OpenSSL

Tags: c++, ssl, openssl

I am working with the OpenSSL library's X509 certificate class, and I need to query the "key usage" extension.

After abandoning OpenSSL's vapourware "documentation", some shot-in-the-dark web searching eventually revealed that I needed to call

```
X509_get_ext_d2i(X509 *x, int nid, int *crit, int *idx)
```

and searching through the objects.h header revealed the proper NID.

Problem is, this call returns a pointer to void, which apparently can point to a variety of structs depending upon what extension one has asked for.

Since none of these appear to be documented, one is left without a way to figure out how to parse what the function returns.

Can anyone point me to a document that actually talks about this, instead of just listing things I can find out for myself (the function profile, which file it comes from, etc)?

Comment: I have no answer, but I'll 2nd the sentiment about the documentation quality for OpenSSL... I'm working with it now also (just starting), and it's horrible trying to find examples or documents for anything beyond simple operations... I feel your pain.

Comment: The only way I figured out how to use the API was to take the commandline tool (source), hack up the code (comment out parameters to the commandline that I didn't need) and trace through.  From there I was able to use the API "docs" to fill in the gaps.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest solutions to read the key usage seems to be

```
X509* x509_cert = ...
// without X509_check_ca x509_cert->ex_kusage always returns 0 (no idea why)
int ca = X509_check_ca(x509_cert);
unsigned long usage = x509_cert->ex_kusage;
```

The resulting values are defined in opensc/pkcs15-init.h

```
SC_PKCS15INIT_X509_DIGITAL_SIGNATURE     0x0080UL
SC_PKCS15INIT_X509_NON_REPUDIATION       0x0040UL
SC_PKCS15INIT_X509_KEY_ENCIPHERMENT      0x0020UL
SC_PKCS15INIT_X509_DATA_ENCIPHERMENT     0x0010UL
SC_PKCS15INIT_X509_KEY_AGREEMENT         0x0008UL
SC_PKCS15INIT_X509_KEY_CERT_SIGN         0x0004UL
SC_PKCS15INIT_X509_CRL_SIGN              0x0002UL
```

I came to that soultion by finding the following code of an openssl source file

```
/* Handle key usage */
if((usage=X509_get_ext_d2i(x, NID_key_usage, NULL, NULL))) {
    if(usage->length > 0) {
        x->ex_kusage = usage->data[0];
        if(usage->length > 1) 
        x->ex_kusage |= usage->data[1] << 8;
    } else x->ex_kusage = 0;
    x->ex_flags |= EXFLAG_KUSAGE;
    ASN1_BIT_STRING_free(usage);
}
```

Comment: My `x509.h` contains the warning: `/* These contain copies of various extension values */` for many of the elements in the X509 struct including `ex_kusage`. Thats probably why it is zero until you call that function.

Comment: you have to check value of `ex_flags` if it has `EXFLAG_SET` that means `ex_kusage` and `ex_xkusage` are set and you don't need to call `X509_check_ca`, you can check `v3_purp.c` for more details

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter (nid) determines the returned type.

Looking at this code:

http://opengrok.creo.hu/dragonfly/xref/src/crypto/openssl-0.9/crypto/x509v3/v3_purp.c#X509_check_purpose

It appears that for the key usage NID, it returns a ASN1_BIT_STRING.  (line 361).